# Same download URL but different download files

Tags: html, excel, vba, download

I'm trying to automate downloading excel files. I want to download an excel file from the main view of a webpage, then change the view and download an excel file representing the second view. The url doesn't change. On the main page, I see the download URL after manually clicking the download button. After changing the view, I will see the same download URL. When I do this manually, I get the proper excel files. When I try to automate the process using VBA, i get the main view excel file with the second view page. I do not want to automate clicking the download button because I would like to control the file destination. I thought sending the 2nd page cookie info would do it, but doesn't appear to be the issue. It was the only thing that looked different in the request headers. Apologies if I'm not asking this correctly. Not a programmer and my first time here. Also hiding the webpage for security reasons.

```vb
Sub Download_Data2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim user As String
    Dim pW As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("example")
    CompanyID = ws.Range("C4")
    user = ws.Range("C15")
    pW = ws.Range("C16")

    CheckUserPass user, pW

    ie.Visible = True

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("https://xxxxID= " & CompanyID & "&xxxxxxxxxxx=true")
        Wait4Load ie
        If Not .document.Url Like "*=true" Then
            Wait4Load ie
            If WaitForElement(ie, ".o-form-input-name-identifier", 5) Then
                UserNamePageInput ie, user
                Wait4Load ie
                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
                PasswordPageInput ie, pW
                Wait4Load ie
            ElseIf WaitForElement(ie, "input[name='credentials.passcode']", 1) Then
                PasswordPageInput ie, pW
            End If
        End If

        Wait4Load ie   

        ' Change period to LTM and load page
        Set listEle = .document.getElementById("_pageHeader_fin_dropdown_period")

        For Each currentListOption In listEle.getElementsByTagName("Option")
            If InStr(currentListOption.innerText, "LTM") > 0 Then
                currentListOption.Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next currentListOption
        Set goButton = .document.getElementById("_pageHeader_TopGoButton")
        goButton.Click
        Wait4Load ie

        Dim stateKey As String
        Dim actionStr As String
        Dim sKele As Object

        Set sKele = .document.querySelector("input[name='stateKey'][id='stateKey'][type='hidden']")
        actionStr = sKele.getAttribute("value")

    End With

    Dim fileURL As String
    Dim destinationPath As String
    Dim cookieString As String
    cookieString = ie.document.cookie

    fileURL = "https://www.xxx/excelReport.aspx?companyid=" & CompanyID & "&statekey=" & _
                actionStr & "&worksheet=40&mode=xxx&myContentType=3"

    Debug.Print cookieString

    DownloadFileWithHeaders fileURL, cookieString


End Sub

Sub DownloadFileWithHeaders(fileURL As String, cookieHeader As String)
    ' Use XMLHTTP to download the file with specific headers
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    ' Add custom headers (including the pageID in cookies)
    http.Open "GET", fileURL, False
    http.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookieHeader
    http.send

    ' Check if the request was successful (status 200)
    If http.Status = 200 Then
        ' Save the file to a local destination
        Dim destinationPath As String
        destinationPath = "C:\Users\joesmith\OneDrive\Desktop\data.xls" '

        ' Use ADODB.Stream to handle binary data
        Dim stream As Object
        Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        stream.Type = 1 ' adTypeBinary
        stream.Open
        stream.Write http.responseBody
        stream.SaveToFile destinationPath, 2 ' adSaveCreateOverWrite
        stream.Close

        MsgBox "File downloaded successfully!", vbInformation

        ' Open the downloaded file with the default associated application
        Shell "explorer.exe """ & destinationPath & """", vbNormalFocus
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to download the file. Status: " & http.Status, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Difficult to know what to suggest without being able to look at the source site.

Comment: My company has a subscription to the website/company. Considering that they're making this difficult and the nature of this company, I'm under the assumption they wouldn't want people automating downloading data. If you think I'm wrong, I'll share the website. I'm just trying to make my life easier with my workflow.

Comment: I can't make any judgement about whether or not it's appropriate for you to share the URL.  Only noting it's difficult to help without access to the site in question.

Comment: @TimWilliams is right. You could study the page source. It probably runs some scripts to control the download source.

Comment: Here's the webpage that has the second view i'm trying to work with. The statekey would be 32 characters, but I didn't include it.

https://web1.capitaliq.com/CIQDotNet/Financial/SelectStatsAndRatios.aspx?CompanyID=+692472&mode=creditstatsdirect&fromSearchProfiles=true&statekey=xxx